# How to list users like an archive page 10 users on page and have navigations

Tags: php, users

How can i list registered users like an archive page? and how can i make a link on user name to point to user profile page?

Please see the link http://postimg.org/image/9wkp6kfib/

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Registered Users
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="art-contentLayout">
 <div class="art-content">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="art-Post">
   <div class="art-Post-tl"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-tr"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-bl"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-br"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-tc"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-bc"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-cl"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-cr"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-cc"></div>
   <div class="art-Post-body">
    <div class="art-Post-inner art-article">
     <h2 class="art-PostHeader"> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'kubrick'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>">Registered Users </a> </h2>
     <table class="tut">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th><b>Poza</b></th>
        <th><b>Name</b></th>
        <th><b>Inregistrat</b></th>
        <th><b>Nume</b></th>
        <th><b>User Level</b></th>
        <th><b>User Role</b></th>
        <th><b>Vezi Profil</b></th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="the-list" class="list:user">
       <?php 
          $wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");
          foreach ( $wp_user_search as $userid ) {
            $user_id = (int) $userid->ID;
            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
                                                $user_picture =  get_avatar($userid->ID, 40);
            $formid = $user_info->formid;
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            echo '<th>' . $user_picture .  '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->display_name . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->user_registered . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->nickname . '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $user_info->user_level . '</th>';
            echo '<th>'; if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) { foreach ( $user->roles as $role ) echo $role; } echo '</th>';
            echo '<th>' . $userid->ID . '</th>';
                                                echo '</tr>';
          } 
                                        ?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
       <tr>
        <th><b>Poza</b></th>
        <th><b>Name</b></th>
        <th><b>Inregistrat</b></th>
        <th><b>Nume</b></th>
        <th><b>User Level</b></th>
        <th><b>User Role</b></th>
        <th><b>Vezi Profil</b></th>
       </tr>
      </tfoot>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div class="cleared"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="art-sidebar1">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would use WP_User_Query instead of WP_User class to find the list of users. I wrote up a snippet to demonstrate this. I haven't tested it, so you might want to rewrite the whole thing. For reference, checkout this blog post http://mattvarone.com/wordpress/list-users-with-wp_user_query/ and the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Pagination_Parameters

```
$per_page = 10;
$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$args = array(
    'role'      => 'Subscriber',
'number'  => 999999      
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$total_pages = count($user_query->get_results()) / $per_page;

$args = array(
    'role'      => 'Subscriber',
    'orderby'   => 'display_name',
    'number'    => $per_page,
    'offset'    => $offset
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
$all_users  = $user_query->get_results();

foreach($all_users as $user) {
    $user_info = get_userdata($user->ID);
    //Format your output here
    echo $user->email, $user->first_name;
}

echo paginate_links( array(
'base'          => $base,
'format'        => '&offset=%#%',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
'total'         => $total_pages,
'current'   => $offset
));
```